# ScrollBar doesn't resize when a JFrame is maximized

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jscrollbar

I have a `JFrame` with a `JScrollPane` with a `Panel`. I want make `JScrollPane` fits the `JFrame` and the `Panel` fits the `JScrollPane` when I maximize it or when I resize it. I'm using `netbeans gui buider.`

When I start the program everything is in place. All three fitting. But I use this command to maximize the screen, and the scroll and the pane do not change...

```
setExtendedState(this.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You've got a layout manager issue where your layout managers are not making the JScrollPane resize when its parent hierarchy resizes. The simplest solution is to make sure that the JScrollPane's container (perhaps the contentPane?) uses BorderLayout, and that the JScrollPane has been added BorderLayout.CENTER.

For more on this, please have a look at the links to the Swing tutorials and other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing) including links to the layout manager tutorials.